# Jquery blackout + popup problem

Tags: jquery

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jxy64/1/)

I'm struggling to understand what is wrong with this code. I am basically trying to make the page 'blackout' and then display the hidden div inside the new div I have create in the JS.

The first line seems to work, creating a blackout div and fading it over the whole page. But the rest of the jquery just doesn't seem to work, because after that a div should be created (forgottenpassword) which is placed inside the wrapper div and then the emailSignupBox should be placed into the fogottenpassword div which should slide down and display.

I'm also getting an error on Firebug saying:

> $("").css("opacity",
>   0.8).appendTo("body").delay is not a function
>   Line 44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load jQuery 1.4 or higher, because .delay() is added in 1.4:
http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/PjpWC/

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  #blackout {
    background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  #box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 3px solid #0000cc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #0000cc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: #fff;
  }
  #blackout:target {display: block;}
  .close {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    padding: 0 12px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  .close:hover {background: #e6e6ff;}
</style>
```

Popup window!
        Close window
      
    
     
    Call a popup window

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).